# database not opening

Tags: oracle, alter-database

While altering a DB to open getting the below error.

```
SQL> alter database open;
alter database open
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kcratr_nab_less_than_odr], [1],
[344], [73], [125], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
```

Comment: Did you upgrade the database recently? Apply a patch? Are you trying to restore the database. You probably need to give more details like OS, database version, etc. You may also need to create a Service Request with Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide further details about what happened previously. Did a hardware failure occur? Also, refer to the .trc files that generally follows ORA-00600 errors in alert.log. If you're on linux and made a default installation, alert log will probably be located at $ORACLE_BASE/diag/rdbms/sid/sid/trace. It contains the main DB events, and it's the first approach while diagnosing Oracle Failures.